# Batch: How to sort the output by Extension

Tags: batch-file, command

I made a concatenated for where the output should be a file listing of Extensions ordered by name. The source which is dragged to the batch is a folder with subfolders.

What I get is:

```
.mp3
.txt
.mp3
.mp3
.txt
.docx
.txt
.docx
```

What I want is:

```
.docx
.docx
.docx
.mp3
.mp3
.mp3
.txt
.txt
.txt
```

Current code:

```
@echo off
chcp 1252 > nul
pushd "%~1"
for /f "Delims=" %%a in ('"for /f "Delims^=" %%b in ('dir /b /s /a-d') do @echo %%~xb"') do echo %%a
pause
```

All I need is sort the output by name but IF i try the sort command it doesn't work:

```
@echo off
chcp 1252 > nul
pushd "%~1"
for /f "Delims=" %%a in ('"for /f "Delims^=" %%b in ('dir /b /s /a-d') do @echo %%~xb |sort"') do echo %%a
pause
```

If possible I would not like to use a text file.

Comment: What is the reason why you would not like to use a text file? Not only will it most likely be quicker, but the `sort` command itself, may use a file in the default temporary directory, to hold its working storage, if the data does not fit in main memory.

Comment: I just think it is better to not use external files if you don't need them, but if it is not possible otherwise I would use a text file....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're very close already with what you currently have, you're just missing `dir`'s `/o` flag to sort the output, combined with the `e` option to sort by extension. If you put everything inside of a code block, you can then sort the output of the entire command after it has completed.

```
@echo off

chcp 1252 >nul
(
    for /f "delims=" %%A in ('dir /b /s /a:-d /o:e "%~1"') do @echo %%~xA
) | sort

pause
```

Comment: Didn't work, as you said yourself, It still orders by sub-folder....

Comment: @RicardoBohner - I have updated the code to perform the sort after everything is displayed. Extensions are no longer grouped by subfolder.

Comment: This one worked, thank you very much...